# How to apply search when entire column has cells with drop-down list in it (jQuery DataTables)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How to apply search when entire column has cells with drop-down list in it (jQuery DataTables)? In my table one column has dropdown list in each cell, I want to apply search for selected value.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [mcve], in order to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External search [plug-in](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search#Plug-in-structure) allows you to search using whatever criteria you might prefer. Below is an example of how it can be done:

```js
//define dataTable object
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  data: [...Array(6)].map((item, index) => {return {id:index}}),
  columns: [
    {
      data: null,
      title: 'Name',
      render: () => `<select>${['Joe', 'Rachel', 'Phoebe', 'Monica', 'Chandler', 'Ross'].reduce((options, name) => options+='<option value="'+name+'">'+name+'</option>','<option disabled selected></option>')}</select>`
    },{
      data: null,
      title: 'Fruit',
      render: () => `<select>${['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'plum'].reduce((options, name) => options+='<option value="'+name+'">'+name+'</option>','<option disabled selected></option>')}</select>`
    }
  ]
});
//define custom search function
var needle = '';
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((settings, row, rowIndex) => [...$(dataTable.row(rowIndex).node()).find('option:selected')].map(option => $(option).val()).some(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(needle.toLowerCase())));
//listen for searchfield input
$('#searchfield').on('keyup', function(){
  needle = $(this).val();
  dataTable.draw();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <input id="searchfield"></input>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to apply this search for single column , because in my table having one column texbox , one drodown

Comment: You mean, you have a column of textboxes and a column of dropdowns and you need to search across entire table (both, textboxes and dropdowns)?

Comment: yes , i need this search

Comment: And just to make it clear for myself: is it `<input>` text box or `<textarea>` text box? And whether there're some more columns, and if so, what are their types?

Comment: one <input> and one <select> remaining plain<td> data

Comment: Check out this demo: https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/moXRBm?editors=1010

Comment: It working , thank you

Comment: In IE 11  => Not working

Comment: How exactly it is not working? Any errors? Where it fails?

Comment: '=>' this one not working in ie, chrome it i working

Comment: Well, I guess it is not only arrow functions but spread syntax (`[...Array(6)]`) along with some ES6 features are not supported by Microsoft's browsers. So, if that's an issue for you, I'm sure, you may adjust the syntax easily.

Comment: i have changed to like this , in ie include not work var needle = '';
            $.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, row, rowIndex) {
                if ($(dataTable.cell(rowIndex, 12).node()).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });